# Mesh size for straining yogurt?

Tags: equipment, yogurt, straining

Usually, I strain small batches of yogurt through a cheesecloth, but cleaning the cloth afterward is cumbersome. I'm thinking to buy an industrial stainless strainer (40cm / 16" diameter, 10cm / 4" tall) with a mesh, akin to a flour sieve.

What's the best mesh size that would work for full-fat yogurt? The factory has all the sizes from 12.5mm to 0.003mm (3µm).

Comment: Come across 200µm but unsure what others hole sizes may work. There is no correlation data between cheese cloth thread count and mesh size anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen [this piece](http://www.salad-in-a-jar.com/family-recipes/how-to-strain-yogurt-the-easy-way) and the [Bouillon strainer](http://www.salad-in-a-jar.com/family-recipes/why-i-love-my-matfer-bouillon-strainer-and-a-tip-you-dont-want-to-miss) mentioned in it? There is no information on mesh size unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I am part of the Instant Pot (pressure cooker) community and we make a LOT of yogurt. I don't strain mine, but others swear by this strainer. I think it's plastic, though, so this won't help if you're trying to avoid it.

[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0091XNL0I/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_dp_T1_CS3DzbDN0MKPP](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0091XNL0I)

Answer (score 0):

[The comments by michael and jolenealaska](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/14032/how-to-strain-yogurt#comment16981_14036) on the answer to [this similar question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/14032/how-to-strain-yogurt), suggest, if no pressure is applied, that a standard mesh strainer can be used.

Unfortunately I don't know what measurement the holes are but this implies that an extra fine mesh is not necessary.